# Insert Landscape page and Insert page with left Margin

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I am building an Office JS add-in for Word and trying to insert a new page with a left margin of 2.5cm and new landscape orientation page. However, I am unable to find any APIs to accomplish this.

I also tried using OpenXML, but it didn't work. Are there any APIs available to achieve this, or is it possible through OpenXML?